# How can I read mocha test suite/case name outside of the file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I need to read/get mocha test suite/case text outside of the file before running the tests. For example, I have a following test suite and test case:

`describe('Login Page: ', () => { it('should login successfully', () => { ... });});`

I want to get text: "Login Page: -should login successfully" from another js file. Is there a way to import and access? What's the best best solution for this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There's a solution, you parse the file, but how does that relate to mocha specifically?

Comment: @pavelsaman I'm building a UI where you can select tests and run them by clicking on a button. And I wanted to put `describe` and `it` blocks' text as description to each test suite.      This is not specifically connected to the mocha, I was curious if there's built in function that can export names or might be useful somehow to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

````
    let suiteDesc = {};

    const data  = fs.readFileSync(filePath, {encoding: 'utf8'});
    if(data != undefined) {
        suiteDesc.path = filePath;

        let dataArray = data.split('\n');
        
        let caseDescArray =[];
        dataArray.forEach( l => {
            if(l.trim().startsWith('describe(')) {
                suiteDesc.title = getOnlyTitle(l);
            }
            else if(l.trim().startsWith('it(')) {
                caseDescArray.push(getOnlyTitle(l));
            }
        });
        suiteDesc.cases = caseDescArray;
    }

    return suiteDesc;
} 

// Removes extra js code from line
getOnlyTitle = (str) => {
    let title = '';
    if(str.includes('\`')){
        title = str.substring(str.indexOf('\`')+1, str.lastIndexOf('\`'));
        return removeVarsFromString(title);
    } else if(str.includes('\"')){
        title = str.substring(str.indexOf('\"')+1, str.lastIndexOf('\"'));
        return title;
    } else if (str.includes("\'")){
        title = str.substring(str.indexOf('\'')+1, str.lastIndexOf('\''));
        return title;
    }
}
//Removes all variables  = ${} from the string template 
removeVarsFromString = (str) => {
    if(str.includes('${')){
        let startIndexJsVar = str.indexOf('${');
        let endIndexJsVar = str.indexOf('}') + 1;
        let jsVarString = str.slice(startIndexJsVar, endIndexJsVar);
        str = str.replace(jsVarString, '');

        return removeVarsFromString(str);
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}```
````